# How to apply separate FOCUS styling to two input fields

Tags: css, input

I am using CSS to style input fields.

But I want to use different styling for different input fields but it seems that I can only set one Input styling focus in a CSS.

I am current using this code to style the focus of input:

```
input[type=text]:focus, textarea:focus , input[type=password]:focus{
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(229, 47, 22, 1);
  padding: 8px 3px 8px 58px;
  margin: 5px 1px 10px 0px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(229, 47, 22, 1);
}
```

Now when I want to over-ride this style for another input field, I am trying to do it by adding this to the class of that input field:

```
.search
{
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(211, 211, 211, 211); !important;
}
```

The browser if ignoring this over-ride and still shows red shadow.

I am sure there is a way out, but cant seem to find the right way to do it.
Any help or suggestions are welcome :)

Comment: remove the `;` before the `!important`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To properly override style settings, use a more specific selector, e.g.

```css
input[type=text]:focus, textarea:focus , input[type=password]:focus{
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(229, 47, 22, 1);
  padding: 8px 3px 8px 58px;
  margin: 5px 1px 10px 0px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(229, 47, 22, 1);
}

input[type=text].search:focus
{
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(211, 211, 211, 211); 
}
```

```html
<input type=text>
<input type=text class=search>
```

Answer (score 0):

The !important cant be after ; so..

```
.search
{
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(211, 211, 211, 211) !important;
}
```

And thats it.

But better solution is to rather use id #search and there is no need for !important